# How to detect end of line with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression, newlines

I'm looking for a way to only execute replacement when the last character is a newline, using `sed`.

For instance:

```
lettersAtEndOfLine
```

is replaced, but this is not:

```
lettersWithCharacterAfter&
```

Since `sed` does not work well with newlines, it is not as simple as

```
$ sed -E "s/[a-zA-Z]*\n/replace/" file.txt
```

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With standard `sed`, you will *never* see a newline in the text read from a file.  This is because `sed` reads line by line, and there is therefore no newline at the end of the text of the current line in `sed`'s pattern space. In other words, `sed` reads newline-delimited data, and the delimiters are not part of what a `sed` script sees.

Regular expressions can be *anchored* at the end of the line using `$` (or at the beginning, using `^`). Anchoring an expression at the start/end of a line forces it to match exactly there, and not just anywhere on the line.

If you want to replace anything matching the pattern `[A-Za-z]*` at the end of the line with something, then anchor the pattern like this:

```
[A-Za-z]*$
```

...will force it to match at the end of the line and nowhere else.

However, since `[A-Za-z]*$` also matches *nothing* (for example, the empty string present at the end of *every* line), you need to force the matching of *something*, e.g. by specifying

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]*$
```

or

```
[A-Za-z]\{1,\}$
```

So, your `sed` command line will thus be

```
$ sed 's/[A-Za-z]\{1,\}$/replace/' file.txt
```

I did not use the non-standard `-E` option here because it's not strictly needed. With it, you could have written

```
$ sed -E 's/[A-Za-z]+$/replace/' file.txt
```

It's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed "s/[a-zA-Z]*$/replace/" input.txt > result.txt
```

Or, the long complex unnecessary way:

> I've found out, this can be done, still using sed, with the help of
>   tr. You can assign another character to represent the end of the line.
>   Another temporary character has to be used, in this case "`". Let's
>   use "~" to represent the end of the line:
>
> ```
> tr '\n' '`' <input.txt >output.txt
> sed -i "s/`/~`/" output.txt
> tr '`' '\n' <output.txt >result.txt
> ```
>
> And then to perform the actual search and replace, use "~" rather than
>   "\n":
>
> ```
> sed -i -E "s/[a-zA-Z]*~/replace/" result.txt
> ```
>
> And then clean up the extra character on the other lines:
>
> ```
> sed -i "s/~//" result.txt
> ```
>
> Obviously, this can all be piped together resulting in something like:
>
> ```
> tr '\n' '`' <input.txt | sed -e "s/`/~`/" | tr '`' '\n' | sed -E -e "s/[a-zA-Z]*~/replace/" | sed "s/~//" > result.txt
> ```

Comment: Not sure I understand... Why don't you just anchor to end of line with `$` ? e.g `s/[a-zA-Z]*$/replace/`

Comment: 2 points: 1) You'd better use `\+` instead of `*` since the latter allows *zero* letters at end of string; 2) You can use a character class `[[:alpha:]]`. So: `sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\+$/replace/' file`

Comment: @glennjackman What's the backslash for before the plus? Wouldn't that match the addition character?

Comment: GNU sed without the `-r` option uses [this regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Comment: I had to use `-i ''`, otherwise it was interpreting the regex as the name of a backup file.

Answer (score 2):

From the (broken) code snippet you posted, you seem to want to replace the newline as well. In that case, regex anchoring by itself can't help you. The following is a solution:

```
sed '/[[:alpha:]]\+$/{N;s/[[:alpha:]]\+\n/replace/}' your_file
```

Broken down:

- `/[a-zA-Z]\+$/{}` means apply whatever comes inside the curlies to lines that match the regex.
- The regex is the one that uses anchoring as seen in [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206923/26909), modified to take [glenn jackman's comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206922/how-to-detect-end-of-line-with-sed/206984#comment349190_206923) into account.
- Inside the curlies, `N` means "append the next line to the active buffer"  (what `sed` calls the 'pattern space')
- Finally the `s///` statement is your required substitution. It now works because the pattern space contains two successive lines and the newline is therefore a part of it.

Answer (score 2):

To find the end of line, just use the **$-sign**:

Without end of line anchor:

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' file
```

With end of line anchor:

```
sed -n '/pattern$/p' file
```