# Substitute entire line while removing newline of that particular line

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm trying to substitute (with `sed`) an entire line containing a specific word *and* the newline at the end. Here the testfile:

```
this # target for substitution
this is a test
another test?
```

Now, I already [posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648984/substitute-only-words-that-have-a-newline) here, and from the [linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206922/how-to-detect-end-of-line-with-sed) post, I understand how to do this in some way:

```
sed 's/^this$/test/g' testfile
```

That works, or at least it seems so, *because* the newline at the end of the word `this` is still there:

```
test # target for substitution but newline is still there
this is a test
another test?
```

Given the above, I'm also fully [aware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206970/409852) `sed` can't match the newline directly (although I do recall that I could use '\n' in certain version of `sed`, but that's beside the point).

I do know how to at least delete the entire word/line and the newline:

```bsh
sed '/^this$/d' testfile
```

Except I need to substitute it instead.

How can I do this? (with `sed` preferably)

Comment: When you also remove the newline, you effectively substitute the lines `this` and `this is a test` by a single line `testthis is a test`. Is that correct? It's not easy to join two lines together in sed; see examples in the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Joining-lines). You could use awk, which can read the next line: `awk -v replacement=test '/^this$/ { getline; print replacement $0 }' testfile`

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct (and coincidentally exactly what i want here) @berndbausch And I always thought it feasible to join two lines together in sed, especially since i vaguely recall doing it once, but don't quote me on that as I'm unsure and don't remember what i did in sed for this...Lastly I really prefer doing this in sed _if possible_, otherwise awk might be fine if that's really the only way

Comment: What if you have two consecutive lines having `this` as the content, the `awk` solution above will replace only the first such line

Comment: Joining lines seems to be feasible, but my simple mind doesn't penetrate the logic in the manual. I think the Perl answer below is the nicest solution (I did not think I would ever call anything related to Perl "nice").

Comment: @Sundeep yes it requires a bit more work. Your solution is much superior.

Comment: I did managed to join lines in my own answer, although didn't find an easy way to substitute at the same time, unless i use `-e` or `;` and do it before removing the newline... @berndbausch

Comment: Does this work? `awk '{if (/^this$/) {sub(/^this$/, "test"); printf "%s", $0;} else print }' file`

Comment: @berndbausch Why shouldn't it be easy to joing two lines in `sed`? There is the `N` command for this. Nothing more simple.

Comment: @NordineLotfi In *all* `sed` versions, you can match a newline in the search pattern with `\n`. What you recall applies to the replacement pattern.

Comment: OH, so that's what it is. Thanks for clearing the confusion i had :D @Philippos

Comment: @Philippos Simply because I tried it and failed.

Comment: @berndbausch What did you try? Using the `N` command? See my answer: It works and it's extremely simple.

Comment: I am not asking a question here :)

Comment: Correct. You are just giving misleading comments. (-;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I understand you, you want to replace a line consisting only of the word `this` and the following newline by `test`, so

```
foo
this
this is a test
```

should become

```
foo
testthis is a test
```

In `sed` you can do simply join the next line with `N` and replace everything up to the newline:

```
sed '/^this$/{N;s/.*\n/test/;}'
```

Comment: Better than mine, Nice :) (and learned a new sed trick too)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest to use `perl` here, syntax isn't that different from `sed` for this case:

```bsh
$ cat ip.txt
this
this is a test
another test?

$ perl -pe 's/^this\n/XYZ/' ip.txt
XYZthis is a test
another test?
```

Comment: yeah, too bad you can't `directly` use newline like this, otherwise would make things easier when using sed...Thanks for this alternative

Answer (score 5):

With GNU sed, you can read all lines into memory with `-z` and do the matching from there, e.g.:

```
sed -z 's/this\n/test/'
```

Comment: Interesting. Seems like using the `-z` flag make the use of `\n` work as expected...

Comment: @NordineLotfi: with `-z` sed assumes the data is delimted by NUL chars (`\0`). For normal files this results in the whole file being read into memory before the sed-script is run.

Answer (score 3):

Turn out doing this, or as other have pointed out "joining" lines in sed is possible:

```bsh
sed ':a;/^this$/{N;s/\n//;ba}' testfile
```

result:

```
thisthis is a test
another test?
```

To also do substitution:

```bsh
sed 's/^this$/test/g;:a;/^test$/{N;s/\n//;ba}' testfile
```

```
testthis is a test
another test?
```

Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853846/12349101) answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way using awk by manipulating the output record separator:

```
$ awk '{ ORS = sub(/^this$/,"FOO") ? "" : RS }1' file
```

---

```
$ sed -e '
    $!N
    s/^this\n/FOO/;t
    P;D
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/^this$/{$0="test"}1'  file
```

In this command, if pattern is found then this is replaced by
replacement.

The remaining work is to remove newline after replacement because newline is still there. `printf` would do that work
because unlike `print` this doesn’t add newline at the end by default.

This is:

```
awk '/^this$/{printf "%s", "test"; next} 1'   file
```

And this works.

Comment: Nice idea, you can simplify it to `awk '/^this$/{printf "%s", "test"; next} 1'`

Comment: @Sundeep Thanks. Answer edited.